# Form Authentication not work in ASP Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a problem with Forms authentication in asp net core, the fact is that when the page loads, I do not see a redirect to my login URL "/Home/Login" (it s correct). Nothing is happend. Here is the code for my Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<EventSchedulerEntities>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.LoginPath =  $"/Home/Login";
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization(); 

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
        });
        
    }
```

If anyone knows why this is happening, please help.
Controller code:

```
[Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Cookie, was clear before start.

Comment: Have you add `[Authorize]` attribute on your `Index` action?

Comment: It was added. Here is the controllers code:
`
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl)
        {
            return View();
        }
`
I try to use different combinations of attibutes but it still not working

Comment: Your question is that the page that does not jump after running the project is always the Index page?

Comment: I expect a redirect after starting the project to login. It doesn’t happen I can freely watch the Index page.

Comment: If you successfully enter your Index page, it means that the verification is passed. It may be that the cookie you logged in before has not expired. You can delete the cookie in your browser and try again.

Comment: If you can, you can share a screenshot of the cookie in your browser with us.

Comment: So, i try to clear cookie, but it didnt help. I also try to open my site in incognito mode and firefox browser.

Comment: So what if you create a new simple project? Will it have the same problem? It works well on my project.

Comment: So, i will try to do it, but are you sure there is no other solution?

Comment: Emmm,because I use the same code as you,and it have no problem.

Comment: Ok, now i will try it

Comment: Which version of asp net core do you use?

Comment: I use .net5.I think the version is not the problem

Comment: You can see my test [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85j9q.gif).

Comment: Well, it s works... I created new project. Thank you so much.

Comment: So, you can look for problems in your previous project :)